# PHP Login system with PDO

Tags: php, pdo, login-control

I have 1 page (index.php) with 2 forms, login n signup.
All i want is when i click the login button, i stay at this page with the forms **gone**!
Just index.php with welcome message.

I have 2 files:
 1. index.php contains 2 forms.
 2. user.php (User class) with 2 functions, login n addNewUser.

This my index file

```
<?php
    $user = new User();
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $user->login($username, $password);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $user->add($username, $password, $email);
    }
?>
<form action='' method='post' accept-charset='utf-8'>
    <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username' autofocus=''>
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'>
    <input type='submit' name='login' value='Login' />
</form>

<form action='' method='post' accept-charset='utf-8'>
    <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username'></br>
    <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email'></br>
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'></br></br>
    <input type='submit' name='signup' value='Sign Up' />
</form>
```

And this is my login function in User.php

```
public function login($username, $password){
    session_start();
    if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=? and password=?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $username);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
            $_SESSION['login'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        } else {
            echo "Wrong username or password";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please enter username and password";
    }
}
```

Pls help me get this done!

Comment: Hash your passwords.

Answer (score 0):

So why not put something like

```
<?php if (!$_SESSION['login']) { ?>
  ... show forms ..
<?php } ?>
```

so the forms show ONLY when no login has been performed?

Answer (score 0):

All of this in index.php:

```
<?php
function login($username, $password){
    session_start();
    if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=? and password=?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $username);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
            $_SESSION['login'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        } else {
            echo "Wrong username or password";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please enter username and password";
    }
}

$user = new User();
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $user->login($username, $password);
}
elseif (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $user->add($username, $password, $email);
}
else
{
?>
<form action='index.php' method='post' accept-charset='utf-8'>
    <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username' autofocus=''>
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'>
    <input type='submit' name='login' value='Login' />
</form>

<form action='index.php' method='post' accept-charset='utf-8'>
    <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='Username'></br>
    <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email'></br>
    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'></br></br>
    <input type='submit' name='signup' value='Sign Up' />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```